# Need help for compiling under linux

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a Makefile and I would like to make a build for 64 bit linux, the problem is that I don't have a linux machine. Could someone compile it for me or explain to me how to do it on mac or windows?

Comment: The Makefile in question : https://github.com/OpenArena-Ioq3/openarena-ioq3

Comment: You can always set up a virtual machine (for instance https://www.virtualbox.org) with a 64 bit Linux and use that?

Comment: I already try it to but it's not compatible on Mac M1 and I try Parallels desktop but I use all of my free trial and it's only 32bit and I want 64bit 

Comment: @WillSmith Try [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app). The [main UTM site](https://getutm.app) seems to suggest it's for iOS only, but it's in fact available and working for macOS, too.  It's not as slick as Parallels, but unlike Parallels it does work now on M1 machines.

Comment: I was literally setting up ubuntu on UTM when you sent me this comment! I had already used it for linux app testing and I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner, thank you!
For other people who are wondering UTM is a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *cross-compiling* – you want to cross-compile for Linux, on Windows or macOS.

A lot of compilers can do that, but it's slightly fiddly to set up, and of course a bit difficult to test, or to determine when you've done it correctly.  I can't tell you how to do it with your particular compiler, but I hope this gives you something to look for in the manual, or to google.

The other route is to use a *build server*.  That's where you use a collection of servers to do builds on Windows, macOS, Linux distro A, Linux distro B, BSD, and so on....  Depending on where you keep your code, you might have access to such build servers.  Again, I can't give you concrete next steps, but this should give you something to search for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will continue to look for cross-compilers for Mac. I have already managed to compile with cygwin on Windows I believe that we can compile for linux also with it.